# ASP.Net Core 2.1 API JWT cookie-less sessions?

Tags: session, asp.net-core, jwt

Is there such thing? Can this be done?
Have sessions based on the JWT token and not on cookies?
Session.Ids change for me on every request. 
Is there any way of knowing the session without cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is a stateless protocol. That means each request is treated uniquely as if the client had never made a request before. Sessions are a way of faking state. The way they work is when the server needs to maintain state, it creates a session and sends the id of that session to the client via a cookie. A cookie is just a response header that indicates that the client should persist a certain piece of data and then send it back to the server with each subsequent request. The client (web browser), then, does this: saves the cookie and sends the cookie back with each request. The server receives the cookie in the request headers, uses it to look up the session and "restores" it, giving the appearance of state.

The important part is the data, i.e. session id, not necessarily the "cookie". In a sense, that means you could potentially replace the cookie with some other mechanism, as long as the client and server still pass the session id back and forth, you're fine. However, cookies *are* that mechanism for web browsers. There is nothing else in the web browser world that will automatically send data back to the server each time a user navigates to a different page (sends a request). If this were an API with a generic client involved, and a programmer on the other end deciding how each request will be formatted, then you can handle it however you want. And indeed, APIs don't typically utilize cookies for this very reason - there's usually better ways to do things than passing cookies back and forth when you have *full* control over the request. That is definitely *not* the case with a web browser, so traditional websites need cookies to maintain state.

JWT is actually irrelevant in this discussion. It's merely a way of formatting data. It is not a replacement for cookies. Your cookies could *be* JWTs, and in many modern web apps they actually are, but the server still sends a `Set-Cookie` header with that, and the client still saves it locally and sends it back with the `Cookie` header.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up. In this particular case I do have control over both API and Angular 6 client. The problem is I did not find any documentation on HOW to do this. I mean, should I send the session id to angular and then make a cookie from there? Keep it in local storage? Should I override the default HttpClient? Seems low level stuff and I thought that this kind of stuff has been thought of and implemented by people smarter than me.:) Can you point me to some documentation? Some best practices security wise, some demo code? Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of any content specifically, but I'm sure there's stuff out there. Yes, you can use local storage, instead of cookies. However, the part I'm unsure about is transferring it back to ASP.NET Core in a way where it would understand it should pull the session id from there. Honestly, unless you're dealing with GDPR (and maybe even then, since session storage should largely be optional anyways), I'd just use the happy path of cookies. Otherwise, you might simply need to dig into the source to figure out how to proceed.

Comment: Cookie indeed. After your answer I started using Postman and did the login and I saw that actually I got a session cookie in the login response. The reason session.id was changing was the lack of the cookie like you mentioned. And the problem for me was that by default angular does not store/send back the cookies in the requests. The only thing I had to do(for all requests) is add `{withCredentials: true}` and the cookie got in the browser and now it's being sent to the API and the session is there!