# Using session state in ASP.NET Core 2.0 app in IFrame

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am creating a chat bot that lives inside an IFrame on clients' sites. The bot itself uses AJAX to communicate with the .NET Core 2 server.

The problem I have is that while the session is persisted as expected when running the chat bot on its own in a browser, running it in an IFrame causes a new session to be created on each request.

Now, the reason for this is that I am using a session cookie and most browsers do not like this approach when working with Iframes. The regular ASP.NET MVC solution would be to use sessionless cookies, but as with so many other landmines in .NET CORE, cookieless sessions are not supported.

So now I'm stuck and I don't know what to do.

Comment: [As this answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074154/asp-net-core-2-1-api-jwt-cookie-less-sessions) HTTP is stateless and sessions are a way of faking state. You *don't* need it at all when you can pass eg a conversationID as a URL parameter and store the state in a database.

Comment: Well that's a valid solution. I am however not permitted to use a database to persist session information or anything else. If you post your comment in answer format, I'll upvote it regardless because it will help someone in future.

Comment: What *can* you use though? In-memory storage won't work with more than one machine which means you won't be able to handle a lot of traffic. Even so, nothing prevents you from using some kind of caching or even a global ConcurrentDictionary. After all, Session storage is an in-memory dictionary too.

Comment: As for an answer, follow Christopher's advice. Cookieless sessions are [a very big security problem](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/10/16/owasp-top-10-asp-net-core-broken-authentication-session-management/) because the session identifier passed in the URL can be hijacked and reused to impersonate the user. Cookies, controlled and secured by the browser, are A Good Thing in this case. If you go on to pass some ID in the URL you should treat it as an authentication token, not just as a conversation ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution: Change a div's content using the AJAX information that is returned. Don't use Iframes at all. There is no requirement to use an iframe.

You only need to use an Iframe when the content returned is a full HTML page. Based on what you said you could just return the DIV content.

To maintain persistence, just set the initial DIV content to be the session state data when the page loads.